# What law used for total energy for system of two objects?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, momentum

We know change in momentum $\Delta P = m \Delta{v}$ for single object. If we want total momentum for system of two objects when no external force. We used newton's 3rd law. It means newton's 3rd allow us for total momentum system of two different objects.

Also we know $\Delta{KE} = \Delta{PE}$ change in energy for single object. What law allow us for total energy for system of two different objects. And how to write it?

Comment: You are talking about conservation of energy when there is no external force acting on the system right? Because that will change the answer to your question.

Comment: My question is very specific to energy, what law at which we can say when no external between two different objects in elastic collision we define energy of that system. Example using newton's 3rd law we can define law of conservation of momentum. Means in momentum newton's 3rd law is the key for two different objects. What law for energy of system of two different objects?

Comment: Law of conservation of energy

Comment: Newton's 3rd law guaranteed for momentum conservation. How it is possible law of conservation of energy itself guaranteed itself.

Comment: By that logic what do you think guaranteed  Newton's third law?

Comment: Plus law of conservation of momentum in itself is kind of an extention to newton's third law

Comment: Because newton's third law is a connection between two different objects. And results which are equal it show law of momentum conserved. What is connection of law at which connection of two different objects for energy?

Comment: You are assumung that law of conservation of energy is defined for one object. But that is not the case.  It is defined for a system and a system can contain more than one object. So it is not that the law of conservation of energy was for one object and now we are using it for 2 objects. It was always for a system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141058/discussion-between-123-and-obinna).

Answer (score 2):

I can see that you have more misconceptions than just the specific query. In particular, you seem to think that classical mechanics needs to write down Newton's 3rd Law (N3L) so that we can guarantee that linear momentum is conserved.

The opposite is true. We now understand that Newton chose a bad way to write down Newtonian mechanics, so that he needed to state N3L so as to enforce momentum conservation. A smarter way to write down classical mechanics is to start from assuming that linear momentum is conserved, and then N3L will be a derived theorem rather than an assumed law.

That is, it is N3L that is weird, and you should not be asking for Conservation of Energy (CoE) to be written in the same weird way that N3L is.

---

In a private chat, OP asks me to simplify nickbros123's answer. Here it follows:

Let the subscripts i and f stand for initial and final, i.e. the two time slices at which we evaluate things. We are considering two particles, labelled by subscripts 1 and 2. First, we cover a basic formula:
$$\tag1KE=\frac12mv^2=\frac{(mv)^2}{2m}=\frac{p^2}{2m}$$
Now, the most general initial collision between the two particles start with arbitrary momenta for the two particles, but it is strictly conserved, so we must have
$$\tag2\vec p_{1i}+\vec p_{2i}=\vec p_{1f}+\vec p_{2f}\overset{\text{def}}=\vec P$$
where this defines the total momentum of the entire system of two particles, simply by addition within a vector framework. Note that in the simplest conception, $p_{2i}$ is pointing in the opposite direction to $p_{1i},$ so that $\vec P$ is small.

Now, let $M=m_1+m_2$ be the total mass, and for later convenience, the reduced mass $\mu=\frac{m_1m_2}{m_1+m_2}=\frac{m_1m_2}M=\left(\frac1{m_1}+\frac1{m_2}\right)^{-1}$ Then, the velocity of the centre of mass of this system is $\vec v =\frac{\vec P}M$

With the above, we can define the relative momentum $\vec p$ by
$$\tag3\vec p_{1}=m_1\vec v+\vec p=\frac{m_1}M\vec P+\vec p$$
and you can check for yourself that you get, for free,
$$\tag4\vec p_{2}=m_2\vec v-\vec p=\frac{m_2}M\vec P-\vec p$$

Then we can get a miracle. Let us write down the general energy of a system of two particles interacting between themselves by a potential:
\begin{align}\tag5
E&=\frac{p_1^2}{2m_1}+\frac{p_2^2}{2m_2}+V(\vec r_2-\vec r_1)\\
 &=\frac1{2m_1}\left(\frac{m_1}M\vec P+\vec p\right)^2+\tag6
   \frac1{2m_2}\left(\frac{m_2}M\vec P-\vec p\right)^2+V(\vec r)\\
 &=\frac{P^2}{2M}+\frac{p^2}{2\mu}+V(\vec r)\tag7
\end{align}
We have a few takeaways from this miracle, called the reduced mass scheme. First of all, the potential simply spectates; as long as it only depends upon the difference of the position of both particles, then its argument $\vec r$ is the conjugate variable of the relative momentum $\vec p$

The reduced mass scheme allows us to separate the motion of the centre of mass $\vec P$ from the motion of the particles inside the centre of mass frame of reference $\vec p$. In so doing, it makes a pair of particles that are translationally free to move about, subjected to any interaction potential between them, into one free centre of mass motion, and a single-particle motion whereby the origin is now special. This is a great simplification, because the difficulty is now only just one single particle.

---

Now look, if you want to conserve momentum, then only $\vec P$ is conserved. This is a strict conservation and thus you can do nothing to change the energy due to the motion of the centre of mass.

It is typical that the potential $V$ covers the full interaction between the particles. If that is the case, then there is no way for energy to be lost, and the statement of the CoE means that Equation (7) covers everything properly, at all times.

Note that the potential can be general. It is thus relatively rare for interactions to lose energy; Obviously it will lose energy if it is a macroscopic entity, but microscopic interactions tend to conserve energy. Noether's theorem proves that time translation symmetry means that there is a strict CoE, but that includes the conversion of other types of energy into heat.

Now, we can model a collision with long ranged or short ranged forces, with a potential that zeroes at infinity: $V(\infty)=0$, in which case the relevant terms are
$$\tag8\frac{P^2}{2M}+\frac{p_i^2}{2\mu}\qquad\text{vs}\qquad\frac{P^2}{2M}+\frac{p_f^2}{2\mu}\qquad\text{as }\vec r\to\infty\text{ in both cases}$$
Again, as long as momentum is conserved, *there is nothing that can change* $P^2/2M$, and all that might change is $p_f^2$ vs $p_i^2$.

Try a simplification first. Consider 1D, then it is clear that, if there is even a collision at all, then $p_f=-p_i$ if energy is conserved. Newton had the smart idea to introduce a new term, called the Coefficient of Restitution (CoR) $e$, to capture the possibility of some loss of energy. i.e. in general, it is $p_f=-ep_i$.

Then, the final energy is
$$\tag9\frac{P^2}{2M}+\frac{e^2p_i^2}{2\mu}\qquad\implies\qquad\text{Loss}=(1-e^2)\frac{p_i^2}{2\mu}$$

Going back to 3D, the CoR allows the final relative momentum $\vec p_f$ to shrink by a factor of $e$, and we can also rotate this relative momentum from its original direction. In the case of elastic collision, $e=1$ and all that is possible is just the rotation. You can easily draw a circle, because a circle (really, sphere) is where $p^2=$ const, and that is captures all the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

The conservation of momentum and energy applies just as well to systems of two or more objects as it does to a single object. For a system of two objects, for instance, you add the potentially energies of each object to their kinetic energies (i.e. $E_{tot}=E_{pot,1}+E_{pot,2}+\frac12mv_1^2+\frac12mv_2^2$), and this quantity is guaranteed to remain constant. In the case of conservation of momentum, you can express each of their momentums as a vector $p=mv$ (note that $v$ is itself a vector), add them together using vector addition, and that *that* quantity is guaranteed to stay constant. Energy and momentum can be exchanged between two particles whenever they interact via action-at-a-distance (like gravitation or electromagnetism), or whenever they undergo a collision.

The only caveat here is that when two objects undergo an inelastic collision (think of two lumps of clay hitting each other), we usually can't say that their total energy is conserved. Obviously, the *system's* total energy is always conserved, but certain kinds of interactions such as inelastic collisions cause part of this energy to be released in the form of sound and heat.

Hope this helps!

Comment: here we are assuming that the objects are not experiencing any external force perpendicular to direction of the conservation of linear momentum right?

Comment: Hello , Thanks for the answer. My question is very specific to energy, what law at which we can say when no external between two different objects in elastic collision we define energy of that system. Example using newton's 3rd law we can define law of conservation of momentum. Means in momentum newton's 3rd law is the key for two different objects. What law for energy of system of two different objects?

Comment: The law is just "conservation of energy" for elastic collisions, meaning that the total energy before and after should be equal. For inelastic collisions, mechanical energy is not conserved, and you just need to focus on momentum.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question. There is a formula for the total kinetic energy of a 2 body system, it is:
$$ KE_{sys/com}= \frac{\mu \vec v_{rel}^2}{2} $$ which tells you the kinetic energy of a system with respect to the centre of mass.

If you know another relation $$KE_{sys/f} = KE_{sys/com}+KE_{com/f}$$  you can extend this result to the 2 body system.

$$KE_{2body/ground}= \frac{\mu \vec v_{rel}^2}{2} + \frac{M_c \vec V_c^2}{2} $$

We also know that the coefficient of restitution $e$ is equal to:
$$e= \frac{\vec v_2 - \vec v_1}{\vec u_1 -\vec u_2} $$ which is basically nothing but:

$$ e= \frac{\vec v_{2/1}}{\vec u_{1/2}}$$ the ratio of relative velocities after and before the collision, but the sign is important.
Rearrange the terms: $$e\vec u_{1/2}= \vec v_{2/1}$$

Kinetic energy before collision (with respect to ground):

$$ KE_{(1)sys/ground}= \frac{\mu \vec u_{1/2}^2}{2}  + \frac{M_c \vec V_c^2}{2} $$

Kinetic energy after collision (with respect to ground):

$$ KE_{(2)sys/ground}= \frac{\mu e^2 \vec u_{1/2}^2}{2}  + \frac{M_c \vec V_c^2}{2} $$

When we subtract final KE and initial KE:

$$KE_{(2)}-KE_{(1)} = \frac{\mu (e^2-1)\vec u_{1/2}^2}{2} $$

Here is where you draw the conclusion, we know that for elastic collisions, $e$=1, which means the term $e^2-1$ becomes 0, this we get:
$$KE_{(2)}-KE_{(1)} = 0 $$

This is the classic result where kinetic energy during elastic collision is conserved.

Comment: Hello , my question is very simple. Newton's 3rd law is way to connection between two body system. Newton's 3rd law guarantees for law of momentum conserved. My question is that what law show the connection between energy in 2 body system and guaranteed energy conserved?

Comment: Law of conservation of momentum is the same law which governs the fact that all elastic collisions have their energy conserved

Comment: Pls show the derivation steps at which we derive law of conservation of energy from law of conservation of momentum.

Comment: This is a valid proof of my own. Elastic collisions have a property that $v_{relative}=u_{relative}. $. The equations I derived are all derived using centre of mass coordinates, and i have derived the energy of a system in terms of centre of mass coordinates. Using conservation of momentum, I can say that the velocity of centre of mass remains unchanged, using elastic properties, I can say the relative velocities are unchanged. Using my relations, along with these, Ive proved that the kinetic energy remains unchanged, in an elastic collision.